# Matching replies using sms on twillio

Tags: twilio

I want to have a flow where I text a user, and that user can text back to trigger an event. I could have multiple outstanding messages to a user at any one time - is there anyway on receiving a text message I can figure out which message it is in reply to, without including an id number in the text message body?

Comment: This is something I am looking for too. Does Nexmo or any other SMS provider offer this feature? Have you managed to find a solution to your issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

So, just to be clear about the problem, it sounds like you have multiple steps in your workflow that might happen in parallel, or at least before the user can response, rather than in a specific linear message/response workflow.  Your app might send out 5 messages, and you want to match up each of 5 replies to a specific message.

If thats the case, then unfortunately there really isn't a direct way built into Twilio to let you match up a message reply without including some kind of ID or command in the response message.

Hope that helps.